# How to output all levels, which length is not equal to 3?

Tags: r, r-factor

I would like to display all levels, which length (as `character`) is not equal to 3 symbols.

The following code returns length of `dt$col` for each row:

```
with(dt, nchar(as.character(dt$col)))
```

But if I pass `levels(dt$col)` as the first argument, it fails with the following error:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :
>   invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

How to count length for each level? How to display levels with wrong length only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new object with your factor levels (using the data from DatamineR's answer, except **NOT** using `factor` as a column name):

```
f <- data.frame(myFactor = factor(c("ABCD", "ABC", "A", "ABCDE", "ABC")))
myLevs <- levels(f$myFactor)
```

Then subset the levels that are not three characters long:

```
myLevs[nchar(myLevs) != 3]
## [1] "A"     "ABCD"  "ABCDE"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `with` you should not be using `dt$`, you can refer to the column names directly.

```
# Some factor data
f <- data.frame(factor = factor(c("ABCD", "ABC", "A", "ABCDE", "ABC")))

# Cont the lengths of the factors
with(f, nchar(as.character(factor)))
[1] 4 3 1 5 3

# Display the levels whose length is not equal to 3
f$factor[with(f, which(nchar(as.character(factor)) !=3)), drop = TRUE]
[1] ABCD  A     ABCDE
Levels: A ABCD ABCDE
```

Comment: I have editted it. You can set `drop = TRUE` within factor subsetting

Comment: Thanks. In result it outputs all values of `factor` column with length not equal to 3 or equal to `<NA>`s and only after that lists `Levels: `. But usage of 'levels` on top of that returns what I need. Btw, please check the output your second line of code, it should return `4 3 1 5 3`.

Comment: You can do that applying `levels` to the last line. But you want the factor levels whose length is not equal to 3 to be displayed, don't you? Isn't this performed by the code?

Comment: Having many-many rows, it displays first list of all rows having "invalid" levels and only after that needed information is listed. So, yes, applying `levels` to the last line helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to do it in one line:

```
(l <- levels(f$myFactor))[nchar(l)!=3]
(function(x) x[nchar(x)!=3])(levels(f$myFactor))
levels(f$myFactor) %>% {.[nchar(.)!=3]}  # uses library(magrittr)
```